# Hide Manager Permissions of Parent

Tags: 2007, permissions, security

In Document library, when clicking on Actions, users have "Manage Permissions of Parent" and "Edit Permissions".

Is there a way to hide the 'Manage Permissions of Parent', as users are accidentally changing the permissions of the parent rather than that of of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A HideCustomAction might be the solution here, or just som custom Javascipt hiding the item in ribbon!

More about HideCustomAction [here from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414790%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, I am not sure whether this is applicable in my case. I am referring to SharePoint 2007. And the page is the edit permissions page of the document library. I am not sure it is possible here to add javascript, or use the HideCustomAction approach.

Comment: You can always inject JavaScript via additionalpagehead delegate, or more prefferably by adding a Content Editor Webpart on the page if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I see it more of a hack than an implementation but it seems the only approach. Thans again